# Once the non provisional patent is submitted to USPTO how long it takes to get the receipt number or patent pending status?

Tags: patent-applications

My attorney finally filed my non provisional patent.
Provisional was filed by me in Aug 2017.
Once the non provisional patent is submitted to USPTO how long it takes to get the receipt number or patent pending status?

Comment: I'm tempted to say less time than getting an answer to that question ;) But who knows (I don't), let's see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it submitted electronically, the filing receipt is immediate. Patent pending starts when it is filed.

Comment: Yes got the email from the attorney. If i know the application #, what is the corresponding US Patent pending #?

Comment: @Ashu There isn't a "patent pending" number per se, just a patent application number (would probably start with 15/* or 16/*).  However, there is probably more harm than benefit for sharing/publicizing this number before publication of the patent, which generally occurs 18 months after the filing/priority date, as it allows competitors to keep tabs on your patents and possibly challenge them before granted.  However, once a patent issues/is granted, you will need to provide the number (see "patent marking") when stating "patented" in order to collect damages in an infringement suit.

Comment: @user132162. Thanks a lot for this information..yes it starts with 15. In my field of work - it's a practice to show US15<remainder of the digits> patent pending in the resume/profile  - is it okay to do so?

Comment: @Ashu It's probably fine, and it does show some "proof" of having filed an application (even though no one else can inspect/verify until it is published).  But if I were running a business, I would not disclose the number or the filing date.